# Port forwarding not working, tried with telnet

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

List of my virtual servers:
[image: 1]

I'm attempting to open the port on my laptop to this port

My results from `ipconfig`:
[image: ipconfig]

(yes the ips are the same)

Even if I turn on DMZ it doesn't work. My router is a Archer VR1600v.

I tested the port forwarding with telnet, but it didn’t work.

Comment: More importantly, when you check the "WAN IP address" in your router's connection status page, and when you google for "what is my ip address", are _those_ IPs the same?

Comment: @user1686 when I search up what my ip is, it's the same as "Ip Address" on the main page. My IPV4 is NOT the same as my router's ip address.

Comment: As intimated by @user1686 It appears you may be behind Carrier Grade NAT. If this is the case, short of using a tunnel/vpn or getting a non CGN IP address you won't be able to port forward, What are the first 2 octets of your WAN address as per your router?

Comment: The point is to check whether the _public_ IPv4 address (i.e. the one that's seen by websites -- not the one in ipconfig!) matches the WAN address shown by your router. If they're different then it's the common "CGNAT" problem. If they're the same, then the problem is probably something else. (For example, TCP vs UDP mixup? PC firewall settings? The service actually not running on that port? Your tests being made from inside the LAN instead of outside?
 The ISP blocking everything?)

Comment: @davidgo my ip changes when router reboots. My current public ip is 203.221.239.97

Comment: @user1686 they're the same. I know the port uses UDP, my pc firewall is off, I am fairly certain the service is running on the port, how do I check? My tests are using the telenet and the is my port forwarded website. I don't know how to check the ISP.

Comment: by "the telenet" do you mean the `telnet` command? You can't test UDP ports with that...

Comment: What OS are you using?   If you are using Windows, what does "netstat -aon" tell you?

Comment: @user1686 my bad, but the actual function of the port being forwarded didn't work.

Comment: @davidgo I just left home, but I'll check for you in a minute. What should I do based on what result?

Comment: (I don't do Windows but) that should let you see if something is listening on the computer on that port.   (If there is nothing listening, it doesn't matter if port forwarding is working).

Comment: Your LAN IP addresses are not private information, please don’t censor them. // Please don’t provide textual information (`ipconfig`) as images. Instead, use a code block. // Testing UDP port forwardings _cannot be generalized_. What’s the service you’re trying to expose? You need a client for this specific service. // You cannot reliably test port forwardings from inside the network. You need to be outside (for example using mobile internet).

Comment: @davidgo that doesn't work

Comment: @Daniel B I have tested it from outside, by attempting to connect to a server. I am basically hosting a server on port 19132, but it doesn't work unless I attempt connecting to the server locally

Answer (score 0):

*Quick intro: Port forwarding is a technology which allows you to access a service on your internal network from the internet. This is required due to insufficiently availble IPv4 addresses, which prevent you from directly assigning an internet reachable address to your machine. Port Forwarding or -Port Network Address Translation- is a workaround(/hack) for this issue. Not all applications will play nice with it.*

The general idea of port forwarding is know your external IP address, activate port forwarding on your router/firwall and then set your application to listen on the designated port you defined in your port forward. Below example setup:

```
Internet --- Router/Firewall --- Laptop -------- Application
5.5.5.5   |  192.168.1.1      |  192.168.1.100       |
          |                   |                      |
  Ext. TCP 19132     Int. TCP 1234                TCP 1234

$ your_application --port 19132 --server 5.5.5.5
```

In your client application (e.g. Chat client) you then connect to the external IP address of your connection (e.g. 5.5.5.5) and with the external port (19132) you defined. The internal port could be different. The internal port and type (UDP/TCP) must match the port of your application (e.g. Chat Server). Google if your application uses UDP or TCP.

As to why you its not working. Check that the firewall ([windows](https://www.firehousesoftware.com/webhelp/FH/Content/FHEnterprise/FHEnterpriseInstallationGuide/24_StaticPort.htm)) on your device is allowing your application to listen. [Check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMMbG.jpg) the public IP on your router and if it is actually a public IP and not a [private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Private_networks) address stemming from Carrier-grade NAT.

---

Things to keep in mind:

- Allow application to listen on that port in computer's firewall

  - If in doubt, disable firewall temporarily and check if works
- External / Internal port do not need to be the same
- Ensure correct Layer 3 protocol TCP/UDP(/all)
- Ensure Port forward is pointing at correct IP of your Laptop
- Public IPs change and may change often based on your ISP

Comment: Sorry but I've already tried that. How do I check the internal port?

Comment: For windows, launch cmd with admin rights and then type: netstat -anb. Look for your application and the line LISTENING. That will show you on what port your application listens.